# How to reverse listview in Flutter

Tags: list, listview, dart, flutter, future

I implemented a `listview` which get data from a `json`.

I followed [this](https://grokonez.com/flutter/flutter-http-client-example-listview-fetch-data-parse-json-background) implementation.

How could i reverse the order of this listview? (The first element should became the last, ecc...).

Comment: Please Refer this link : [Reverse of List in Listview Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55095773/reverse-list-in-listview-builder-in-flutter)

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You should be able to reverse the list before feeding it to the `ListView`.

```
List<String> animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'duck'];
List<String> reversedAnimals = animals.reversed.toList();
```

Answer (score 38):

For `ListView` there is a flag called `reverse` which is *false* by default. Change it to **true**

Comment: No. at some point your list is not reverse by using reverse : true. It started pointing your all list from bottom of Listview. So better is to reverse your array.

Answer (score 32):

In **ListView** has an attitude is **reverse**, set it is *true* to reverse your list:

```
ListView.builder(
      reverse: true,
);
```

Comment: This reverse:true takes to the last element of the list when clicked, so this is not the perfect solution.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution with **null safety** support of reverse the listview.
Do not use reverse:true because it will reverse your data but when you open listview.builder widget in your app it will take automatically to **scroll to the last item**.
To avoid that use this:-

```
ListView.builder(                  
                  itemCount: customer?.data.length ?? 0,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    int itemCount = customer?.data.length ?? 0;
                    int reversedIndex = itemCount - 1 - index;
                    child: Container(
                     child: Text(value.allCustomerModel!.data![reversedIndex].attributes!.name.toString(),
                      ),)
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of reversing `listview`, get your list reversed using [reversed property](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-core/List/reversed.html) or [reverse function](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/package-collection_collection/reverse.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can reverse the order of your list before returning the ListView element.

```
ListView.separated(
    itemCount: widget.orderList.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
       final reversed = widget.orderList.reversed.toList(); // reverse your list here
       final item = reversed[index]; // assign it with index
       return Text(
           item.name, // the item name in my list
          ),
      },
      // The separators
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
         return const Divider(
            color: Colors.grey,
         );
        },
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **conditionally** reverse the List that you are passing to the ListView, you can use this extension:

```dart
extension ListExtension<T> on List<T>{
  List<T> reverse(bool condition){
    return condition ? reversed.toList() : this;
  }
}
```

and use it as `[].reverse(yourCondition)`
(dont forget to import this extension if you have defined it in some other file)

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse it simply like it ==>>

```
ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        var reverselist = snapshot.data!.reversed.toList();
```

and Then can be used as ==>

```
     Text(
             reverselist[index]
                                            .tituloCategoria
                                            .toString(),
                                                                            

                                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      ),
```

`

Answer (score 0):

**Example :**

```
List data = [
     {
        "number" : 1,
        "iterator" : 0
     },
     {
        "number" : 2,
        "iterator" : 1
     },
     {
        "number" : 3,
        "iterator" : 2
     },
   ];
```

**On ListView ... **

```
ListView(children: [
   for (var i = data.length; i > 0; i--) ... [
      Text(data[i]["number"].toString())
   ]
])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      List<int> number1 = List.empty(growable: true);
  if (number1.isEmpty) {
    number1.add(2);
    number1.add(9);
    number1.add(5);
    number1.add(6);
    print(number1);
    number1.sort();
    number1=number1.reversed.toList();
    print(number1);
  }
```

Comment: Please explain your answer, otherwise this post may get deleted

Comment: Why check if the list is empty? You literally just created it. And why sort? That changes the order of the original array.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
List<int> reversedNumbers = numbers.reversed.toList();
```

Comment: Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should [vote it up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Answer (score 0):

```
SingleChildScrollView(
      reverse: false,
      child: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        reverse: true,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          return Container();
        },
      ),
    )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).