# Reverse list in ListView.builder in Flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I wanted to reverse list and I have achieved this by using  `reverse: true,`. It is working, but the list has aligned to the bottom and showing blank space at the top when the list has least items.

```
 Expanded(child:  ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                reverse: true,
                controller: _scrollController,
                itemCount:order_response.orderDetails.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, position) {return orderListItemTile(width,height,order_response,position);},
              ),)
```

[image]

But when I deleted `expanded()` widget, when items increase then it overflows by pixel.

```
 ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            reverse: true,
            controller: _scrollController,
            itemCount:order_response.orderDetails.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, position) {return orderListItemTile(width,height,order_response,position);},
          ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Reverse your list using:

```
var reversedList = _response.orderDetails.reversed.toList();
```

Comment: `val` cannot be used to declare a variable in Dart. Maybe you're confused by its usage in Kotlin or something? `final`, `var` or using the type itself is appropriate in this case.

Comment: Worked very good.

Answer (score 33):

Apart from reversing the list, another solution could be putting the `ListView` inside an `Align` widget with `alignment: Alignment.topCenter` . Also `shrinkWrap: true` needed inside `ListView`.

```
         Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: ListView.builder(
              reverse: true,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              ...
              ...
           )
         )
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this solution works because it shrinks the `ListView`, so you'll have to handle the pain that comes with not having a fullscreen `ListView`. (such as scrolling within it)